# Get list of items based on indices from list of indices

Tags: python, list

I have a list called `a`.
I have a list of indices called `b`.

How do I set all the elements of `a` with indices in `b` to 0 ?

In other languages I could do `a[b] = 0`, this returns the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`, I am not sure what the efficient pythonic way of accomplishing this is.

Both `a` and `b` may be fairly large.

```
#we are given this:
a = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]#some list
b = [2,3,6,9]#some set of indices

#we aim to get this:
c = [6,8,14,20]
```

Edit to provide a sample code.

Comment: `for i in is: a[i] = 0` You cannot have a variable named is

Comment: What other languages allow you to write `a[is] = 0`? Not C, PHP, or Lisp.

Comment: @Barmar numpy arrays allow you to do that

Comment: You can also convert `a` to a numpy array like `a = np.array(a)`. Then, `a[is] = 0` works.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I didn't consider nympy a language.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, just trying to provide some context on why the OP could consider this possible. Also don't now if Matlab lets you do something like that

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yeah, there are applications that do this, but none of the most common languages.

Comment: Numpy and Pandas can do this. If these libraries shouldn't be used, what's the use case exactly? Otherwise, writing a loop seems to be all that's left.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Matlab does allow you to do this, as does numpy (although I am not sure how efficient it is on large lists). I assume most languages have some alternative method of efficiently getting a specific subset of a list, I was asking what the most efficient method in python was.

Comment: Voting to reopen, I think the question is now clear with the added example. And the solution is simple: `c = [a[i] for i in c]`. Or use numpy arrays, as was previously said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering this question based on some of the comments, as it was at the time locked due to me being unclear and not providing an example.

We can get `c` as required by either using list comprehension :

```
#Solution 1, use list comprehension
c = [a[i] for i in b]
print(c)
```

or numpy:

```
#Solution 2, convert to numpy
a = np.array(a)
c = a[b]
print(c.tolist())
```